# Right way to do class hierarchy in a package

Tags: python

I'd like to know the right way to do define a multi-layer class hierarchy in a package.

For example, say I have these classes:

```
class Furniture:
class Table(Furniture):
class Chair(Furniture):
class Armchair(Chair):
```

etc..

In my calling code, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
import furniture
my_chair = furniture.chair.Armchair()
my_table = furniture.Table()
```

I can't seem to get my head around what class definitions and imports I should put where for this to work - both to have my calling code work nicely, but also to have the `Armchair` able to see the `Chair` class.

As a note - I don't ever expect to instantiate the mid-level classes, just `Table` and `Armchair` in this example, but never `Chair` or `Furniture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ tree -I __pycache__ furniture/
furniture/
├── chair.py
└── __init__.py
```

`__init__.py`

```
class Furniture:
    pass

class Table(Furniture):
    pass
```

`chair.py`

```
from . import Furniture

class Chair(Furniture):
    pass

class Armchair(Chair):
    pass
```

and your code:

```
import furniture
import furniture.chair

my_chair = furniture.chair.Armchair()
my_table = furniture.Table()
```

---

The note: Then you probably want to prefix the *Furniture* and *Chair* classes with an underscore, as this marks it as protected.